# How to ask same question again on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, questions

If I am not satisfied with the answer for a question that was asked and answered on Stack Overflow? How can I raise the same question again, without breaking Stack Overflow laws?

For example, I feel it would be good to have better answers for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701587/can-someone-explain-the-arguments-to-write-function-used-for-the-curl-option-cur).

Comment: Identify the parts of the answer you feel are missing, and then ask that question.

Comment: Why do you think that you will get different answers if you re-ask it? Do you plan to change something about how the question is asked, or are you just going to re-ask the exact same thing?

Comment: There's a bounty option exactly for this purpose, but you don't have enough reputation to do that yet.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/366904/cody-gray I still feel some more explanation is needed since there is very little documentation available to understand clearly.

Comment: Side note: "read documentation and explain it to me" kind of questions usually not accepted well on SO. It is very hard to make such question concrete... and if there is source code for library such question is likely collect well deserved downvotes.

Comment: By editing your question to make it more clear, you are able to get to answer better

Answer (score 9):

You cannot ask the question again, because it would be closed as a duplicate. You *could* post a new question, but you have to be *very* careful and state exactly why the original *question* (not the desired answer) is different from yours.

The last (and best option, once you have the necessary reputation [(75)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties)) is to put a *bounty* on the question, with one of the following [bounty reasons](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/09/bounty-reasons-and-post-notices/) (depending on your exact needs):

> #### Current answers are outdated
>
> The current answer(s) are out-of-date and require revision given recent changes.
>
> #### Improve details
>
> The current answers do not contain enough detail.

You can put additional comments in your bounty notice, to specify exactly what you are looking for in an answer.

Comment: _"but you have to be very careful and state exactly why the original question (not the desired answer) is different from yours."_ You could also explain why none of the answers answers your specific question. (The common guidance) If the answers don't answer your question, it's really not a duplicate. However, you _really_ have explain _why_ the answers don't work for you: Errors, specific restrictions they hit, etc.

Comment: What if the duplicate has no answers at all, but later another person needs an answer on this question? One way would be to set bounty on the old, but what if the user has not enough reputation yet?

Comment: @TimSchmelter on main sites, you can't close a question as a duplicate unless the target has answers (or was asked by the same user).

Comment: This was [referenced in comments](https://arstechnica.com/civis/threads/after-chatgpt-disruption-stack-overflow-lays-off-28-percent-of-staff.1496474/post-42278082) to the 2023-10-16 article *"[After ChatGPT disruption, Stack Overflow lays off 28 percent of staff](https://arstechnica.com/civis/threads/after-chatgpt-disruption-stack-overflow-lays-off-28-percent-of-staff.1496474/)"* (referenced in the MSE post *[What is the best way to keep Stack Overflow strong now that we have ChatGPT?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/393914/)*) (near *"at least once or twice"*).