# Should I ask same unanswered question again after finding more information, or edit original question?

Tags: support, questions, edits

So recently I ran into a seemingly unsolvable problem and as a last resort posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50430108/d3d11createdeviceandswapchain-does-not-swap-to-full-screen-on-2nd-monitor) on Stack Overflow. Unfortunately the question drew very little attention and researching even more revealed that there are more people running into the same problem who asked this on other forums (mostly steam) and got no response.

With a couple of helpful comments on my question I was able to narrow down the cause of the problem even further and considered asking a new question about the same problem.

Checking whether that's even allowed I found [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339624/how-to-ask-same-question-again-on-stack-overflow) asking *how*
to do it and the response is:

> You cannot ask the question again, because it would be closed as a duplicate. You could post a new question, but you have to be very careful and state exactly why the original question (not the desired answer) is different from yours.

Now obviously the question is still identical; only the information that could lead to an answer is a lot different. Also unlike in that question, my question got no answer at all and edits now are not likely to make a difference.

So my question is - Is there a point where the information about the same problem is so different that it becomes okay to ask the same question again? If yes, should my old question be deleted?

Comment: Is there a problem with editing the question? Editing is the usual procedure here.

Comment: Well editing in this case would be equivalent to rewriting the question from scratch. It would be like a brand new question - that's why I'm wondering if it's okay to actually ask a new one. Looking at the information I have right now, the only thing in that question that would stay unchanged is the title.

Comment: That is a bit inaccurate: questions keep a revision history and a permanent link. The old version becomes "hidden" in the history.

Comment: You seem to have new information about the same problem. And so, that is usually worth being added to the original question. I really can't see how a new separate question would benefit anyone in this case: visitors would still find the old one not useful, and potential answerers could be wasting their time on a solved problem.

Comment: That's why I asked if the old question should be deleted to avoid problems you just mentioned. A benefit I see is that the more polished version of this question would get some attention and would be potentially answered much quicker.

Comment: Here's a misunderstanding. Edits will bump your question to the top of the active question queues. So you will get the attention that you are looking for with just the edit. If you need more, consider placing a bounty.

Comment: I see. I guess that answers my question. My thought process was that if I ask how to fix B, but problem B is caused by A, can I ask how to fix A instead. I assume information about A should be simply appended to the original question then. Thank you

Comment: Please don't edit your question radically or ask new questions **if someone has answered it already** and the edit would invalidate that answer. You have no answers on your current question, so editing is fine, but just keep it in mind for next time. You may want to consider deleting any irrelevant comments once you've edited it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edit** the original question, just like how you deal with downvoted questions.

Editing the original question also bumps up the question, so it is generally pointless to recreate the new question.

Comment: i disagree. unfortunately stack overflow didn't want to reset score when edited